# Python 2D array with same values

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and I am doing a task for school. The task is to assign 4 constant variables and then use a code to work out the value. Each value has a corresponding letter and the program is asking the user to type in 5 numbers then the program will return the word. The code is the following:

```
array = [["L","N"], #define the 2d array, L=Letters, N=Numbers
        ["-","-"]] #line for space

a = 2#define the variables
b = 1
c = 7
d = 4

e = (a*b)+b#calcualtions
f = c+b
g = (d/a)-b
h = c*a
i = a+b+d
j = c-a
k = c-d*f
l = c+a
m = (c*a)-b
n = a*d
o = a+d-b
p = (c*d)-a*(b+d)
q = a*(c+(d-b))
r = (d*d)-b
s = r-f-g

array.append(["e",e])
array.append(["f",f])
array.append(["g",g])#append all the calculations
array.append(["h",h])
array.append(["i",i])
array.append(["j",j])
array.append(["k",k])
array.append(["l",l])
array.append(["m",m])
array.append(["n",n])
array.append(["o",o])
array.append(["p",p])
array.append(["q",q])
array.append(["r",r])
array.append(["s",s])

def answer():
    len_row = len(array)
    number_input = int(input("Enter number: "))
    for i in range(len_row):
        if number_input == (array[i][1]):
            return array[i][0]
            break

one_let = answer()
two_let = answer()
thr_let = answer()
fou_let = answer()
fiv_let = answer()

print(one_let,two_let,thr_let,fou_let,fiv_let)
```

The numbers that I am meant to put in are 6, 18,, 7, 8, and 3.

The word that prints is "spife" and the word that is meant to be printed is "spine". The problem is that there are two letters that have a variable of 8 and Python gets the first one only. Is there a way to print out the two seperate words but first with the first variable in a 2D array and second with the second 2D array? i.e spife then spine

Thank you for your help ahead, I am just a beginner! :)

Comment: Are you allowed to change the calculations?

Comment: No, the calculations have to stay as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it but is a bit tricky the secret is to use `itertools.product` on the list of letters that could have each of the five values.

First you need to use a better data structure such as a `dict`, (in this case a `collection.defaltdict`) to hold the letters that have some value. You can do this way:

```
import collections
import itertools

a = 2#define the variables
b = 1
c = 7
d = 4
e = (a*b)+b#calcualtions
f = c+b
g = (d/a)-b
h = c*a
i = a+b+d
j = c-a
k = c-d*f
l = c+a
m = (c*a)-b
n = a*d
o = a+d-b
p = (c*d)-a*(b+d)
q = a*(c+(d-b))
r = (d*d)-b
s = r-f-g

dat = collections.defaultdict(list)
for c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrs":
    dat[eval(c)].append(c)
```

Now in `dat` you have a list of letters that match some number, for example

```
print(dat[6])
print(dat[18])
print(dat[7])
print(dat[8])
print(dat[3])
```

Outputs:

```
['s']
['p']
['i']
['f', 'n']
['e']
```

OK, then you need to change `answer`to return a list of letters, and collect the user input:

```
def answer():
    number_input = int(input("Enter number: "))
    return dat[number_input]

letts = [answer() for _ in range(5)] #collect five answers of the user
```

And the final magic is done here:

```
for s in map(lambda x: "".join(x),itertools.product(*letts)):
    print(s)
```

Now if you are confused then study:

1. [collections](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#module-collections)
2. [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
3. [itertools](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools)
4. [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
5. [str.join](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join)

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, I will have a look at the modules, thank you :-)